# Dual boot ubuntu problem

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning

I am trying to have a dual boot Ubuntu with Win 7 on my laptop.I face a problem i couldn't understand.After I free a space(about 11GB) for Ubuntu installation, I couldn't find it when i try to install Ubuntu from a DVD.I couldn't specify the problem reason is it due to my Hard drive partitioning or not.
My hard drive volumes (Partitions) are all simple volume not primary.
here a snapshot of my disk management
 http://oi42.tinypic.com/dpd7oj.jpg
here is how i find my hard drive during installing Ubuntu
 http://oi44.tinypic.com/21b9fs4.jpg
instead of finding my volumes with the free space.

Could any one help me how to solve this problem or even declare the problem for me in a more detailed view.is it the simple volumes problem or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate the space on your 11gb partition set it to fat or something that the computer can recognize so when you install you can choose that specific space for your install.

Comment: ok i will try but i would like to know if the simple volumes here  http://oi42.tinypic.com/dpd7oj.jpg will be a problem and i have to make them primary volumes by a way or another.

Comment: another problem i want to understand how ubuntu installation show me my partioins as
sda1 unknown    1     MB
sd2  ntfs       208   MB
sda3 ntfs       261.2 GB
sda4 unknown    238.7 GB

while my hard drive is partitioned in totally diferrent sizes
C               243.28 GB
Ismail          195.33 GB
System          199 MB
HP_tools        99 MB
Recovery        15 Gb

when i look to installing pic partitions I say "is it another hard drive".

Comment: I believe 208mb and the 1mb its for hard drive partition information. Its wanting to install a separate file system on the rest of the space on your drive.

Comment: You are showing dynamic partitions not basic. Dynamic is a logical overlay over the physical partitions that Linux can see. If you want to use Linux you have to undo the dynamic partitions. Really good backups required. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx And 
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html

Comment: I Fix this problem by backing up my data and restore my lap top to factory status then the partitions became primary again and i could see them in installation in a right way with the free space but i couldn't add partition of Ubuntu partition and swap partition because the add button is nonactive .How Could i step over this new problem while i have 4 primary partitions C,System,Recovery,HP_tools.